# How to skip(not rollback) for exception in @Transactional method?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, exception

My goal is to validate update logic before it queries to the database. Also this validation should not rollback or fail on request. It should just skip failed iteration in `for-loop` logic(logging would be enough) and go next iteration.

I created custom `Hibernate interceptor`, that validates request "before SQL querying" at the end of transaction. That's how I understand it.

I check current and previous field value in `boolean onFlushDirty` overriten method and throw `org.hibernate.CallbackException`(as it throws in `Interceptor` interface method signature) if validation failes.

In my non-transactional service method I have `for loop` where I execute another method that can cause this exception. `repository.save()` method is transactional and method throws `JpaSystemException` instead of `CallbackException` when validation fails...
So I catch it and don't throw anything - just logging. That's why failed iteration is skipped and service method continues its work.

But I need to have transactional service method to have option to rollback for other exceptions and ***keep*** "skipping Hibernate interceptor exception when it caught" finishing method successfully.

I tried to add

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = JpaSystemException.class)
```

But it doesn't work for me. I also tried to noRollBackFor others exception, I tried to throw custom exceptions instead of `CallbackException`. It didn't fix problem.

What should I do in my situation?

Comment: I don’t know how it will work though, as save works on an entity with relationships: One leaf might have a validation issue, but the root already marked for save means the context (and so the transaction)is now in an invalid state. You would have to separate the validation out to happen before persistence logic, which means writing your own save method anyway. If you do- return something instead of throwing exceptions if the validation doesn’t force a rollback so that the caller knows what occurred and they can continue